# How can I check if item version was published

Tags: publishing

I want to display all versions published of an item in Sitecore. I'm working with `master` database because in `Web` database we have just the last version published.

How can I found this `status:published` version or not of the item?

I'm working with `Sitecore 8.2 update 4 with SXA`

Thanks

Comment: I think you are going to have to compare web DB to the master DB. http://www.jondjones.com/learn-sitecore-cms/sitecore-developers-guide/customising-sitecores-ui/how-to-display-the-published-status-of-an-item-in-sitecore

Comment: Maybe you can use some of these snippets https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/how-to-find-out-whats-pending-to-be-published

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Marek, "all versions published" sounds weird as there will always be only one version published (per language).

But to give you an idea of how you can fetch this information from the master database: if you have an `Item` object called item, you could do something like:

```
foreach (var version in Sitecore.Context.Item.Versions.GetVersions(true))
{
    version.Publishing.IsPublishable(DateTime.Now, false)
}
```

This will loop through all versions of the item in all languages (that is the `true` parameter in GetVersions). For each version it will check if it is publishable today without taking note of the ancestors. This is just an example with the `IsPublishable` function - you have more functions available in `publishing`.

Comment: @ Gatogordo, 'version.Publishing.IsPublishable(DateTime.Now, false)' gives information if it's publishable ant not it's published and I didn't found any functions in publishing that's gives informations about published

Comment: What information are you looking for exactly? A history of published versions? The current one (this is in web)? Can you clarify the question..

Comment: Yes I need to found the history of published versions. For example if the item have 3 versions cretaed in EN language. the first and second version were published and not the third. I want to got the information that these 2 versions was published and to found their content

Comment: Do you use workflow?

Comment: I'm using  the out of the box sitecore **Sample Workflow**  but using it we can get a workflow state(Draft, Approve, waiting approve) and not published.

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore only one version of an item in given language is published at a time.

If you have an item with `version 1` in EN language, you publish it, then there is version 1 published in the web database.

If you then create another version, `version 2`, you publish it, then `version 1` is not published anymore, only `version 2` is published.

If you need to find all the published versions, just check what is in `web` database.

Comment: I want to find all the published versions but in the **web** just the last version published will be in the **web** database. How can I found for example version 1 if I published version 2

Comment: But version 1 is no longer published. Do you mean that you want to find an information which version was ever published in the history, even if only for 1 second?

Comment: Yes I need to found the history of published versions. For example if the item have 3 versions cretaed in EN language. the first and second version were published and not the third. I want to got the information that these 2 versions was published and to found their content

Answer (score 0):

You can get detailed item wise publish report using Sitecore module "SITECORE PUBLISH REPORTING KIT" available on marketplace at https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_Publishing_Reporting_Kit_SPRK.aspx

[image]