# Report for Approved workflow state that are created/updated in last 30 day

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have to create a report via Sitecore Powershell where I have to fetch all items in Approved workflow state that are created/updated in last 30 days. I am getting the data but seems there are inconsistency in data.

I have tried with the script as shown below:-

```
$workflowStateID = Get-Item -Path master: -ID "{C674D9DF-B5EA-4F3B-8871-F80B2F214F28}"
$referringItems = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $workflowStateID | Where-Object { $_.__Created -gt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-30) }

#EmptyArray
$listofWorkflowItems = @()

#$listofWorkflowItems

#Skip System Items
Foreach($item in $referringItems) { 

    $itemPaths = $item.Paths.FullPath
    if($item.Paths.FullPath.contains('/sitecore/content/abc-website'))
    {
        $rendering = $item | Get-Rendering

        $addInList = New-Object System.Object
        $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ID -Value $item.ID
        $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Path -Value $item.FullPath
        $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Created -Value $item.Created           

        if($item.'__Never publish' -eq 1)
        {
            $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name NeverPublished -Value 'True'
        }       
        if($rendering){
            $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name URL -Value $item.FullPath.Replace("/sitecore/content/abc-website/home","https://abc.com") 
        }

        $listofWorkflowItems += $addInList
    }
}

$listofWorkflowItems | Show-ListView
```

But I am not getting through with if condition for Never publish property of item.

I have gone through with [How to find out what's pending to be published](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/how-to-find-out-whats-pending-to-be-published) where if condition is mentioned for never publish property. But its not working at my end.

Also the date filter is not working as expected. With the below syntax for items created in last 30 days, I am getting items created in 2017 as well.

```
$referringItems = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $workflowStateID | Where-Object { $_.__Created -gt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-30) }
```

Is there something in syntax which I am missing?

Any help/pointer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you rebuild the link databases for the date filter issue and for the Never publish property add an `else` condition :-

```powershell
if($item.'__Never publish' -eq 1) {
    $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name NeverPublished -Value 'True'
} else{
    $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name NeverPublished -Value 'False'
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working on local environment after rebuilding link databases. I'll mark your comment as answer once tested on other environments.